# EndpointHandlerMapping : Did not find handler method for message in the logs

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

I have a simple @RestController setup in a spring boot application. I have spring filter setup that hits this "/desktop/sessionTimeoutCheck" to make sure user session is still active. It works for most of the time and then it stops working.

When I look at the logs I see the "did not find hanlder" DEBUG level message but I know that this controller is being hit based on the "In desktop session handler" message I am printing. Is it normal to see this message or does this mean something is wrong with the controller setup?

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/desktop/sessionTimeoutCheck", method = GET)
public ResponseEntity<RestResponse> sessionCheck() {
    System.out.println("SessionController: In desktop session handler");
    return new ResponseEntity<>(new RestResponse<>(null, MessageSeverity.SUCCESS, "Done"), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Logs

```
o.s.b.w.f.OrderedRequestContextFilter    : Bound request context to thread: Request(GET //localhost:8080/desktop/sessionTimeoutCheck)@6bb79ef4
o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Looking up handler method for path /desktop/sessionTimeoutCheck
 o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Did not find handler method for [/desktop/sessionTimeoutCheck]
SessionController: In desktop session handler
o.s.b.w.f.OrderedRequestContextFilter    : Cleared thread-bound request context: Request(GET //localhost:8080/desktop/sessionTimeoutCheck)@6bb79ef4
```

Comment: Share your project structure and your filter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It’s normal.

When the dispatcher servlet receives a request, it calls each of its handler mappings in turn to find a handler for the request. It stops searching once it has found a matching handler and dispatches the request to it. In this case the matching handler is the method on your session controller.

The debug logging from `EndpointHandlerMapping` shows it being called as part of the search for a matching handler. It responds that it doesn’t have one. The search continues till the handler for your controller method is found.